# I get 'Bad assignment' when trying to use $(this) inside function after .load() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I couldn't find any solutions for my problem yet. Maybe I used wrong keywords.
I'm trying to update the value of an input field onchange after a .load() action has been performed.
Here is my script:

```
$(document).on("change",".myInput",function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#actionDiv').load("someAction.php?value="+value, function() {
        $(this).val('OK');
    });
});
```

So, after someAction.php has been loaded into #actionDiv successfully, I'd like to change the value of that input field, that has been changed.
I have several input fileds, which take this kind of action...
It seems "$(this)" is unknown in the function after load() has been completed.
Can anyone please help?
Thanks

Comment: The context of `this` changes inside the `load` callback, you can assign `$(this)` to a variable and use it inside the callback.

Comment: `$(this)` changes inside `.load`, it is no longer a reference to your input but to `#actionDiv`, save the reference to the input before you enter your `.load` function. some like this: `var $input=$(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store a reference to the element, or use an arrow method which doesn't change the value of `this`

```
$(document).on("change",".myInput",function() {
    var that = this;
    var value = $(that).val();
    $('#actionDiv').load("someAction.php?value="+value, function() {
        $(that).val('OK');
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on("change",".myInput",function(e) {
    var value = $(e.target).val();
    $('#actionDiv').load("someAction.php?value="+value, function() {
        $(e.target).val('OK');
    });
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on("change",".myInput",function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    $('#actionDiv').load("someAction.php?value="+value, () =>{
        $(this).val('OK');
    });
});
```

Comment: Or even better, use a [fat arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) `() => {/* Your code here*/}` construct.

Comment: "arrow function" is a fat arrow.  Last example.

Comment: You are awesome!! That did it for me :-) Thanks a lot